# Transformation to dgamma function in Python

Tags: python, statistics

I want to transform data

[0.54667, 0.471447, 0.826591, 0.330514, 0.7263, 0.496063, 0.520698, 0.321594, 0.351358, 0.894333]

to distribution

'dgamma(a=0.91, loc=0.48, scale=0.15)'

How to do in python

Comment: have you checked scipy before?  https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gamma.html

Comment: I had seen and tried. I was not able to do and hence asked for second opinion on how to do. Please help if you understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to generate an distribution object in advance. All you need would be the distribution params using codes below.

```
from scipy.stats import gamma
import numpy as np

data = [1,2,3,4,5]  # your data

fit_alpha, fit_loc, fit_beta = gamma.fit(np.array(data), floc=0, fscale=1)
```

Then, you can use scipy.stats.gamma funtions to get PDF/CDF/ec. Like:

print(gamma.pdf(0.9, fit_alpha))

Check out the [documentations](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gamma.html) to find the useful calls.